# How to replace all the values in one file with their corresponding names from another file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I need help in substituting values (numbers) in one file (File-1.txt) with those of names (string) in another file (File-2) containing the values in first column and corresponding names in the second column. The two files are as below:

File-1.txt

```
(0, ':', [])
(1, ':', [18])
(2, ':', [20, 41])
(3, ':', [18])
(4, ':', [17])
(5, ':', [])
(6, ':', [])
```

File-2.txt

```
1   ALA_A_87
2   THR_A_127
3   GLY_A_128
4   ILE_A_130
5   THR_A_166
6   THR_A_167
```

Expected Output:

```
(ALA_A_87, ':', [THR_A_127])
(THR_A_127, ':', [ALA_A_87, GLY_A_128, ILE_A_130])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [THR_A_127, 5])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [THR_A_127])
(THR_A_166, ':', [GLY_A_128, THR_A_167])
(THR_A_167, ':', [THR_A_166])
```

I have been trying some awk code, but no luck!! The awk code is as below:

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN {
        subs="ALA_A_87 THR_A_127 GLY_A_128 ILE_A_130 THR_A_166 THR_A_167";
        split( subs, subs_arr );
    }
    NR == 1 { 
        print; 
        next 
    } 
    NR>1{
        for i in {1 2 3 4 5 6 }; {
            $i = subs_arr[ $i++ ];
        }
        print
    }
' File-1.txt
```

Here, I provided the names and values to be substituted in the code itself, but if it can be provided as an external file (File-2.txt) and matching the numbers in the File-1.txt with that of first column of File-2.txt and replace the numbers in File-1.txt with the corresponding names shown in File-2.txt. Help me resolve this code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How should your expected output be?

Comment: I encourage you not to apologise for errors, especially ones that don't invalidate the post. You should make changes (if you think you need to) and move on. Your opinion is as valid as everyone elses.

Comment: @EdMorton: <strike>Do we REALLY have to wade through your long first sentence being rude to the OP?</strike> *"I feel like five lines of data would do it"* would suffice.

Comment: @EdMorton: I felt that your comment was unnecessarily rude and wordy, ironically when you were commenting about the OP being rude and wordy, so I said so. Why did you feel the need to be sarcastic when it was necessary only to point out that the data could be cut down? My `<strike>` tags are valid HTML, which work in posts but not in comments, and I saw no other way to convey the same intent. Your comment had an effect only because of the humility of the OP, mine was ineffective because you had no such humility, and chose to argue and counterattack instead of correcting your mistakes.

Comment: @EdMorton: Are you saying that *"Do we REALLY need to wade through 50 lines of input"* wasn't meant to be sarcastic? You seem to have conveniently dropped the capitals, and it doesn't read as a genuine question to me. I'm not interested in responding to your efforts at defending your rudeness any more.

Comment: Of course it wasn't meant to be sarcastic. What could possibly be read as sarcastic about it? I simply wanted the OP to think hard about whether or not we really had to see 50 lines of input and gave my opinion that about 5 lines would do. I'm also done with this conversation and YOU are the only one being rude in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk one-liner should help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{FS="[(,]"}sub(/[^,]*/,"("a[$2])+1' f2 f1
```

It outputs something like:

```
(, ':', [])
(ALA_A_87, ':', [18])
(THR_A_127, ':', [20, 41])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [18])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [17])
(THR_A_166, ':', [])
(THR_A_167, ':', [])
(LYS_A_189, ':', [])
(GLY_A_190, ':', [45])
(ALA_A_191, ':', [])
(GLY_A_192, ':', [26])
(MET_A_193, ':', [23])
(LEU_A_194, ':', [])
(THR_B_200, ':', [37])
.....
```

**Note** the first line, the `0` doesn't exist in file2, so there is an empty in the `()`, if this is not what you want, please let me know what value should be there.

Comment: Kent, if the name for the code does not exist, so I dont need anything to be replaced. I have posted an edited form of question for more clarity. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Asha this would be a tiny modification.  just a check `$2 in a` I still don't understand the downvote... :( because it is too short?  You have already got solution? or should I update the answer?

Comment: Please don't enquire about the reason for people's downvotes. They would have explained to you if they intended to, and asking about it pretty much never gets an answer. Votes are anonymous for a reason, and while it may be frustrating to lose points without being told why, that's the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

I really wasn't sure which numbers were supposed to be replaced but this one replaces the ones inside `[]` as it felt more interesting. You should always provide expected results:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
       {
            b=$0;
            gsub(/^.*\[|\].*$/,"",b); 
            if(split(b,c,", ")) 
                for(i in c) 
                    sub(c[i],a[c[i]],b);
            sub(/\[.*\]/,"[" b "]",$0)
       } 1' f2 f1
(0, ':', [])
(1, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(2, ':', [CYS_B_237, SER_D_310])
(3, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(4, ':', [ASP_B_234])
...
```

**Edit**: Added a version for @NeronLeVelu:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
               { for(i=2;++i<=NF;)
                     sub(/[0-9]+/,a[substr($i,match($i,/[0-9]+/),RLENGTH)],$i)
               } 1' f2 f1
(0, ':', [])
(1, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(2, ':', [CYS_B_237, SER_D_310])
(3, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(4, ':', [ASP_B_234])
...
```

**Another edit**: After the requirements clarified (`2`->`0`), this is the working version:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
               { for(i=0;++i<=NF;)
                     sub(/[0-9]+/,a[substr($i,match($i,/[0-9]+/),RLENGTH)],$i)
               } 1' f2 f1
(, ':', [])
(ALA_A_87, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(THR_A_127, ':', [CYS_B_237, SER_D_310])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [ASP_B_234])
```

Comment: Careful with `sub()`s using input data as the regexp or replacement as they fail cryptically when the input contains regexp metacharacters (e.g. `. * ? +`) and/or backreference characters (e.g. `&`).

Comment: @EdMorton Speaking of warnings, is it really not possible to use `&` as a reference to an array in `sub`, as in: `sub(/[0-9]+/, a["&"], $i)`?

Comment: That should work just fine. Are you getting a warning about it?

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(i=2;++i<=NF;)sub(/[0-9]+/,a["&"],$i)}1' f2 f1` just returns empties, like: `(2, ':', [, ])` with above data.

Comment: @EdMorton Hmm, if I add `& foo` to file `f2`, I get `(2, ':', [foo, foo])`.

Comment: Of course. `&` didn't exist in f2 so `a["&"]` was a null string then when you did add `&` as an index you got what it maps too, `foo`.

Comment: Naturally I wanted to use the numeric value that `&` would reference to in the regex but I guess it's not implemented that way.

Comment: Oh, hang on... are you trying to get the `"&"` in the array index to be interpreted as the backreference? No,you can't do that, nor can you use it as the argument to a function `sub(/X/,tolower("&"))` etc as you might like.. That's one of the uses for the 3rd arg to match(): `match($0,/(.*)([0-9]+)(.*)/,b) { $0=b[1] a[b[2]] b[3]}` and `match($0,/(.*)(X)(.*)/,b) { $0=b[1] tolower(b[2]) b[3]}`

Comment: @ James Brown and @ Ed Morton, I expect all the numbers in File-1.txt to be replaced i.e both inside [ ] and outside. I know i wasn't clear in my previous post but now i have edited the question for more clarity. I apologise for that

Comment: @Asha That's easy, use the latter code and change the `2` in the `for(i=2;...` to `0`: `for(i=0;...` I kind of expected that...

Comment: wouaw, let me look at it once again :-) ... Got a new version (with new constraint that are easier for omptimization)

Answer (score 1):

in case this is the second part of the file2 that are names to substitute

```
awk 'FNR==NR{n[$1]=$2;next}
    {
    h=$0;gsub( /\[.*/, "[", h)

    N=$0;gsub( /.*\[|].*/, "", N)
    NsS = split( N, aNs, /,[[:blank:]]*/)

    printf( "%s", h)
    for ( i=1; i<=NsS; i++) printf( "%s%s", (i==1 ? "" : ", "), n[aNs[i]])
    printf( "]\n")
    }
    ' File-2.txt File-1.txt
```

Challenged by James Brown speed and ability, a second version :-)

```
awk -F '[][[:blank:],]*' '
    FNR==NR{split($0,t,/[[:blank:]]*/);n[t[1]]=t[2];next}
    {
    printf( "%s, %s, [",$1, $2)
    for ( i=3; i<NF; i++) printf( "%s%s", (i==3 ? "" : ", "), n[$i])
    printf( "])\n")
    }
    ' File-2.txt File-1.txt
```

reply to the internal "challenge" with @JamesBrown and with last OP info (change all number of F2)

```
awk -F '[^[:digit:]]*' '
    FNR==NR{n[$1]=$2;next}
    { for ( i=1; i<NF; i++) sub( $i, n[$i]) }
    7
    ' File-2.txt File-1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the files are unsorted, i.e. line *m* in *File-1.txt* matches line *n* in *File-2.txt*, where *m* may not be equal to *n*. (At the time of writing, you haven't mentioned if the files were sorted.)

One way to solve this problem is to build a hash from *File-2.txt*, read *File-1.txt* line by line, and substitute the values using the hash for each line.

**Example in Perl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename1 = 'File-1.txt';
my $filename2 = 'File-2.txt';
my %hash;
my $fh;


open($fh, '<', $filename2) or die "Failed to open $filename2: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, $value) = split;
  $hash{$key} = $value if $value;
}
close $fh;


open($fh, '<', $filename1) or die "Failed to open $filename1: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  s%^\(\K(\d+)%$hash{$1} // $1%e;
  print;
}
close $fh;
```

*Sample Output*

```
(0, ':', [])
(ALA_A_87, ':', [18])
(THR_A_127, ':', [20, 41])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [18])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [17])
(THR_A_166, ':', [])
(THR_A_167, ':', [])
...skipped...
(LEU_D_391, ':', [30])
(ASN_D_399, ':', [8])
(TYR_D_402, ':', [])
(SER_D_404, ':', [8])
(NAO1, ':', [])
```

---

If you want to substitute *all the numbers*, then it is even easier. Replace this substitution:

```
s%^\(\K(\d+)%$hash{$1} // $1%e;
```

with this:

```
s%(\d+)%$hash{$1} // $1%ge;
```

*Sample Output*

```
(0, ':', [])
(ALA_A_87, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(THR_A_127, ':', [CYS_B_237, SER_D_310])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [ASP_B_234])
(THR_A_166, ':', [])
...skipped...
(ARG_D_325, ':', [ASN_B_399, LEU_A_194, VAL_B_396])
(LEU_D_391, ':', [SER_B_310])
(ASN_D_399, ':', [GLY_A_190])
(TYR_D_402, ':', [])
(SER_D_404, ':', [GLY_A_190])
(NAO1, ':', [])
```

You might apply this substitution for the entire file contents as well.

---

Note, I have used `%` as the regular expression delimiter instead of the usual slash, because otherwise it is impossible to use the `//` operator within the substitution.

Note, the original expression

```
s/^\((\d+)(.*)$/'(' . ( $hash{$1} || $1 ). $2/e;
```

was not optimal, because:

- the `(.*)$` part was unnecessarily processed;
- the first `(` might be kept intact with the help of `\K` option;

The expression was not quite correct because of the use of *OR* operator. If the key doesn't exist in `$hash`, then `$hash{$1}` is `undef`ined. And the `//` operator is more appropriate, as it returns the right-hand operand only if the left-hand operand is undefined.

Comment: `s/^\(\K(\d+)/ $hash{$1} || $1 /e;` in case you don't really need `$2`

Comment: Thank you Osmanov  for the code, but I require all the numbers of the File-1.txt to b e replaced by their corresponding names given in File-2.txt. I know, the confusion was from my side and I apologise for not posting the expected output

Comment: @Asha, then it's easy, just replace the substitution `s/^\((\d+)(.*)$/'(' . ( $hash{$1} || $1 ). $2/e;` with `s/(\d+)/$hash{$1} || $1/ge; `

Comment: Why does your substitution delete the whole of the rest of the line and then put it back again?

Comment: You unnecessarily add `(.*)$` to the end of your pattern, which matches and removes the *whole* string, and then put it all back again by appending `$2` to the replacement text.

Comment: @Borodin, ah, you mean that in the first part of the answer I could simply write `s/^\((\d+)/'(' . ( $hash{$1} || $1 )/e;`, right? Fixed this.

Comment: That's correct. You also need to use `//` instead of `||`, although it doesn't matter with the example data.

Comment: @Borodin, actually I tried `//` at first, but it failed to compile: `syntax error at 1.pl line 22, near "$1 )"`. Oops, it's because of the regex delimiter `/`. I need to use another character

Comment: And I would use `\K` ("keep") to avoid having to replace the opening parenthesis: `s/ ^\( \K (\d+) /{ $hash{$1} // $1 }xe`. And while you're reading, `%hash` is a terrible name for a hash :)

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I missed that. You simply need to change the delimiters for the replacement string. Braces `{...}` work well here as they emphasise that the replacement is executable code because you have used `/e`. I've fixed my code sample above. You can use them for the regex pattern too if you don't like having a mixture of delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl

This builds a hash `%convert` directly from the contents of `File-2.txt` and builds a regular expression from its keys. It then checks each line of `File-1.txt` for a non-empty pair of square brackets, and converts all numbers within into the corresponding value of the hash

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %convert = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'File-2.txt';
    map { split } <$fh>;
};

my $re = join '|', keys %convert;
$re    = qr/\b(?:$re)\b/;

open my $fh, '<', 'File-1.txt';

while ( <$fh> ) {
    s/($re)/$convert{$1}/g;
    print;
}
```

#### output

```
(0, ':', [])
(ALA_A_87, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(THR_A_127, ':', [CYS_B_237, SER_D_310])
(GLY_A_128, ':', [GLY_B_235])
(ILE_A_130, ':', [ASP_B_234])
(THR_A_166, ':', [])
(THR_A_167, ':', [])
(LYS_A_189, ':', [])
(GLY_A_190, ':', [LEU_D_391])
(ALA_A_191, ':', [])
(GLY_A_192, ':', [ARG_B_304])
(MET_A_193, ':', [ASP_B_241])
(LEU_A_194, ':', [])
(THR_B_200, ':', [SER_B_404])
(MET_B_201, ':', [])
(ASP_B_232, ':', [ASP_D_234])
(ILE_B_233, ':', [ASN_B_399])
(ASP_B_234, ':', [THR_B_200])
(GLY_B_235, ':', [])
(SER_B_236, ':', [])
(CYS_B_237, ':', [LEU_D_311])
(SER_B_238, ':', [GLN_B_305, ASN_B_240])
(ASN_B_240, ':', [GLY_B_235, MET_A_193, GLN_B_305, ARG_B_304])
(ASP_B_241, ':', [GLU_B_398])
(ALA_B_279, ':', [])
(GLU_B_280, ':', [])
(ARG_B_304, ':', [ASP_B_241, GLY_A_128])
(GLN_B_305, ':', [MET_A_193, VAL_B_396])
(ARG_B_308, ':', [ASN_D_399])
(ASP_B_309, ':', [THR_A_167])
(SER_B_310, ':', [])
(LYS_B_313, ':', [SER_B_238])
(LEU_B_391, ':', [ARG_B_308])
(TYR_B_395, ':', [MET_A_193, ARG_D_325, GLU_B_398, GLN_B_305])
(VAL_B_396, ':', [])
(GLU_B_398, ':', [ASP_B_309])
(ASN_B_399, ':', [LYS_A_189])
(SER_B_404, ':', [ARG_B_308])
(GLY_C_192, ':', [])
(ASP_D_234, ':', [ASP_B_309, LEU_D_391])
(ASP_D_309, ':', [])
(SER_D_310, ':', [ARG_D_325, LYS_A_189])
(LEU_D_311, ':', [THR_D_314])
(THR_D_314, ':', [ASN_B_240, GLY_B_235])
(ARG_D_325, ':', [ASN_B_399, LEU_A_194, VAL_B_396])
(LEU_D_391, ':', [SER_B_310])
(ASN_D_399, ':', [GLY_A_190])
(TYR_D_402, ':', [])
(SER_D_404, ':', [GLY_A_190])
(NAO1, ':', [])
```

Comment: I apologise for not providing the expected output from the code. I want all the numbers in File-1 to be replaced with names irrespective to the side of " : "

Comment: So what should happen to zero `0` in `File-.txt`? It's much simpler this way; I've changed my answer so that it leaves numbers that don't appear in `File-2.tx5

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/s:\\b\1\\b:\2:g/' file2 | sed -rf - file1
```

This turns file 2 into a sed script that acts as a lookup for file 1.